# how to understand Sequentially-consistent and happen-before?

Tags: c++, sequential, consistency

```
// Thread 1:
x.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // A
y.store(1, std::memory_order_release); // B
// Thread 2:
r1 = y.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // C
r2 = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // D
// Thread 3:
y.store(3, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // E
r3 = x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst); // F
```

is allowed to produce r1 == 1 && r2 == 3 && r3 == 0, where A happens-before C, but C precedes A in the single total order C-E-F-A of memory_order_seq_cst (see Lahav et al).

Because I am a novice, I have been confused when looking at the memory model recently. I would like to ask how to treat this sentence "A happens-before C"? Shouldn't we generally think that the happens-before between different threads should have a while loop to do synchronization? Does the context here mean that if C happens to be loaded to the value stored in A (but it may not be loaded, because it is not a while loop)?
In addition, how to understand A happens-before. C, but C precedes A in single total order. From the perspective of Thread B, A happens-before C, then the result of A execution C is visible, why does C precedes A appear?

Comment: I believe you referenced https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order and suggest to read the whole paragraph instead of just the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The following contents use many levels of markdown item lists which may be difficult to view on the **mobile devices**.

Recently I also read the same cppreference section and has the same question as you at first and got the idea after viewing related SO QAs and papers. I hope this answer can also help you understand what the cppreference says.

---

Your question seems to be a *duplicate* of [QA_1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73446334/21294350) and [QA_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70554277/what-is-the-significance-of-strongly-happens-before-compared-to-simply-happ), but both QAs seem to not read the original [paper_1](https://plv.mpi-sws.org/scfix/paper.pdf) which is referenced in the [cppreference_1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering) and [paper_2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html). So here I will give one answer mainly based on the paper_1 and partly based on its reference [paper_3](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2837614.2837637) from perspective  of **mathematics** which may help grasp the inner ideas if having mathematics basic knowledge.

These are based on my understanding of the papers and related links. *Please point out errors if any*, thanks in advance.

##### Short answer:

1. View the quote in QA_1 question, you will get the occasion where the above **conflict** occurs based on the **old c++11** standard.
   And the QA_1 answer says how this can occur in the real world (can be due to the cache **consistency** which cause different threads see different order of **different** variables).
2. More specifically, view the **Figure 3 with its context**, (S1fix) context and related terminology definitions in the paper_1

   - "A happens-before C" corresponds to `S(k, m)`

     - A is **sequenced before** (sb) B (This is because they are in the same thread by [cppreference_2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Ordering))
       B **synchronized with** (sw) C about the variable `y` but not about `x`, so A happens before C.
       (This is definition of "happens before": a sequence composed of sb and sw.)
   - the total modification order "C-E-F-A" corresponds to `S(m, o, p, k)` (here I coalesced different `S(,)` by order).

     - here `S(p,k)` is due to "reads-before" (IMO, this means "reads-before-write" due to [image]. It is to solve with the WAR hazard).
   - Then the above causes the **cycle**, so in the paper_1 it says "What Went Wrong and How to Fix it" context and it **redefines** in (S1fix). The **c++20** standard is now based on it as the paper_2 says.

     - Here you can think that it splits the original cycle (i.e. **old c++11** total modification order) into two parts `S(k, m)` and `S(m, o, p, k)` where the former stays "happens-before" and the latter is the **new** total modification order.
   - To be more specific, the original question can have one observation order `(A)-B-C-E-D-F-A` (here "(A)" means it runs before but **observed later**.)

     - here A not synchronizes with C, so there is no must that A needs to be observed by C.

Notice: *maybe* the above optimized memory model introduced in c++20 is still flawed. However, I'm not one compiler/computer architecture expert, so it's beyond my abilities to find the flaws.

##### TL;DR (search for something you don't understand after reading the paper_1) Detailed answer mainly based on the paper_1:

The following needs some knowledge of discrete mathematics and I add some description for someone temporarily not familiar with them.

###### If you don't want to be stuck with the "math", then view the following "non-math" part is enough.

Notice: here only some symbols are rephrased, you may better **view the original papers** if has some questions about some terminology.

1. math
   Part of the following primitive symbol definitions (mainly about relation) can be seen from "Notation 1" in the paper_1 like  and "Definition 8" in the like `(;)` paper_3 which is referenced in the paper_1.

   - Here I **assume** that they take same math **primitive** symbols in their the papers because paper_1 "Remark 1" says:

     > The reason we **use Batty et al.’s version** here is that it provides a **cleaner** starting point for our discussion, and our solution to the problems with C11’s SC semantics will build on it.

     And after viewing the paper_3 footnotes in p5, it is mainly based on the ISO standard and maps them to the *pure math* which may be more intuitive if having better mathematics knowledge.
   - [image] (`x` [meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations).)
     Here `;` is [composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations#Definition)(i.e. [image] means one pipeline like `[A] -> R -> [B]`).
     This means one AB pair has the relation R.
2. happens-before definition:

   - non-math

     - See [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#9) (better than cppreference ones because of the 2 levels) which is referenced in both above 2 QAs.

       > A is dependency-ordered before B, or

       This implies including **consume**.
     - As the paper_1 says:

       > Besides the new SC and NO -THIN - AIR conditions, RC11 differs in a few other ways from C11.
       > It does **not support consume** accesses

       So the above cppreference definition may be more general than the following math definitions from the paper_1.
   - math
     [image]

     > Next, we say that one event happens before (hb) another event if they are connected by **a sequence of `sb` or `sw` edges**

     - `+` means transitive (i.e. **sequence**) and `U` means "or".

     above `S(k,m)` has the "happens-before" relation because of the `S(l,m)` synchronization(This is due to `l,m` have data dependency implied (i.e. m read the write of l))

     - definition of `sw`

       - non-math
         think as the `rel`,`acq` sequence like the other [section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Synchronizes_with) of cppreference_1 says.

         > If an atomic store in thread A is a **release** operation, an atomic **load** in thread B from the **same** variable is an acquire operation, and the load in thread B **reads** a value written by the store in thread A, then the store in thread A synchronizes-with the load in thread B.
       - math (see the paper_1 for more details)
         [image]

         > Next, a release event a synchronizes with (sw) an acquire event b, whenever b (**or**, in case b is a fence, some sb-prior read) reads from the release sequence of a (or in case a is a fence, of some sb-later write).

         - From above, the reflexive symbol `?` implies "or" relation.
         - The [image] means partial order with equal, so [image] **includes the `sc`** from the bottom-right figure in p7 of the paper_1.
         - And the `[F]` is always explicity placed by **weak** architecture like POWERPC referenced in the paper_1 which is related with `rel` or `acq`,etc (see this [link](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) from the paper_2 for how the compiler adds these fences).
         - `rs; rf` is implied by `rel` and `acq`
         - [image] is to take RAR (read after read) in account.
         - definition of `rs`
           in the definition of `rs`, `rf; rmw` is to get the sequence like "write,read,write".
         - **In summary**, the above means "rel_event,(fence-sync),release_relation,read-from,relaxed_read,(fence-sync),acq_event"

           - here "relaxed_read" exists because it doesn't influence the relation between `rel` and `acq`.
   - definition of `sb`. Here I take the definition in the paper_3 to highlight that they are in the **same thread**.

     - non-math
       From cppreference_2:

       > Sequenced before is an **asymmetric**, **transitive**, pair-wise relationship between evaluations within the **same** thread.
     - math
       [image]
       Then `sb` means:

       > a **strict partial order** (i.e., irreflexive and transitive) between events from the **same** thread, that captures the program order.

       - "strict" [meaning](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrictOrder.html)

       and the `thd`:

       > an equivalence relation on **non-initial** events that relates events from the same thread.

       `I`:

       > a set of **initial** events. Every initial event [image] is a **non-atomic write of zero**; that is, kind (e) = Wna and wval (e) = 0.Moreover, there is exactly one initial event per location.
3. definition of the single total order (`S` in the paper_1)

   - non-math
     as the paper_1 says:

     > there should be a strict **total** order, S, over all **SC** events, intuitively corresponding to the order in which these events are **executed**.
   - math from the paper_3

     > the S relation relates, in a **strict total** order, **all and only** the SC events in an execution; that is,
     >
     > [image]

     - here `id` is "identity relation"
     - the [image] implies the `S` order is **runtime** defined.
     - the `acy(S)` (S is acyclic) is significant because this caused the above example failure.
4. relations of "the single total order" and "happens-before" and reasons for changes

   - original version in c++11 from the paper_1:

     > (S1) S must include hb restricted to SC events
     >
     > (formally: [image]);
     >
     > [...] (these with no problems found by the paper unchanged)

     non-math: `S` needs to be conform to the hb (happens-before) order
     math: see the above equation.

     - How this make problems -> see above "A happens-before C".
   - why the original c++11 model fails with specific examples?
     Because it **drops of `sync` fences**. Then it implies the [weaker](https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/) memory model.

     - quotes in the paper_1 "Fixing the Model":

       > Conversely, if we follow the leading sync convention, the hb-path (in Fig. 3) from k to m ending with an sw edge **avoids the fence** placed before m.

       And see paper_2:

       > On the other hand, this outcome is **allowed** by the Power implementation. Power normally uses the "leading fence" convention for sequentially consistent atomics. ( See [http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) ) This means that there is **only an lwsync** fence between Thread 1's instructions. This does **not** have the "cumulativity"/**transitivity** properties that would be required to make the store to x visible to Thread 3 under these circumstances.

       - notice: here "this outcome" is that **cycled** outcome (which is not allowed by original language specification expectation but occurs on the machine)
       - Here it says POWER not has transitivity about memory fence, this [depends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58018828/21294350) on the architecture.
         (the above references [`isync`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43944411/21294350) which probably used at the end to ensure the right context and avoid "intra-process reordering" by [refetching](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=set-isync-ics-instruction-synchronize-instruction). I never programmed POWERPC, so I only offer the related reference links and it's not from my experiences).

     The above 2 quotes mean same about how drops of synchronization fences occurs. (i.e. `hwsync` by "Store Seq Cst" by `sc` is avoided and only `lwsync` exists)

   from the paper_1:

   > So, if requiring that hb (on SC events) be included in S is **too strong** a condition, what should we require instead?

   - So based on the above, it has the following changes:

     - non-math

       > The essential insight is that, according to either compilation scheme, we know that a **sync fence** will necessarily exist between SC accesses a and b if the hb path from a to b **starts and ends with an sb edge**. Second, if a and b access the **same location**, then the hardware will preserve the ordering anyway.

       See above "[F]" about the sync fence.

       > (S1fix) S must relate any two SC events that are related by hb, **provided** that the hb-path between the two events **either** starts and ends with sb edges, or starts and ends with accesses to the **same location**

       - The above "either" cases plus implied same-thread `sb` (because this won't cause cycle by the program order) are allowed now in c++20 **instead of** the whole `hb` (happens-before).
       - "same location" is implied by synchronization.
     - math

       > (formally: [image], where [image] denotes hb edges between accesses to the same location).

       `hb` -> `sb...` (i.e. the total modification order `S` doesn't take the whole `hb` in account now in c++20)
   - how changes make work:
     After changing, the example pattern `sb;hb` is dropped. (view Figure 3: `S(k,l)` is `sb`) (Specifically to say, `hb=sw`). So the old happens-before `A,C` is **not take in account now** in the total modification order.

     - There are other examples also work after changes, try them if you are interested.